# Simple Gossip Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a problem which it is the following:

- In a world with $n$ people $k$ of those know a secret.
- At the start those $k$ people will tell the secret individually to $d$ random other people (every person could be within or without the subset $k$). Ex: $k_1 \rightarrow \{d_{11},d_{12},...,d_{1d}\}\; k_2 \rightarrow \{d_{21},...,d_{2d}\}$
- Every person that receives the secret and has not yet executed step 2 also executes step 2.

Basically the problem is a simple gossip example. Some people have a secret and will each share it with a group of other random people. Every person who heards about the secret for the first time will also share the secret to a random group of other people.

Is there any work or papers i could read regarding this simple problem? I only need to show that the probability that every person hears about the secret is high and every problem i find regarding this gossip protocols are much more complicated than this.

Comment: It is typical to treat this as a sort of infection model and then it is very amenable to Markov theory. In discrete time one models the number of people who have heard the rumor, $I_m$ and the people who haven’t, $S_m$, such that $I_m+S_m=n$ at all times $m$ for some fixed constant $n$. Then the process $(I, S)$ is given transition chances, say, $(i,s)\to (i+1, s-1)$ with chance $p$ and $(i,s)\to (i,s)$ with chance $q=1-p$. The chance of hitting state $(n, 0)$ can be computed by a recursion relation via a basic theorem about hitting probabilities. Are you interested in this sort of reframing?

Comment: Another alternative could be the coupon collectors formulation. Here instead, you randomly select at each time, $m=1,2,\dotsc$, one out of the $n$ people to hear the rumor, with replacement. Then usually one is concerned with how long on average does it take for all $n$ people to hear it. Its been discussed many times on this site.

Comment: Yes the coupon collector is not really what i'm looking for as i don't want to explain that i need $x$ rounds to reach a certain number of people with high probability. I only need to explain that after everyone that hears a secret has shared with a group of people, the average number of people who have heard the secret is close to $n$.
I believe the infection idea you said before is feasible for my idea modelling it with a binomial distribution. Where i would have 3 arrays, one for the person who already shared the secret, one for the ones who will share and one for the ones who dont' know..

Comment: then i would just compute for the round $n$ where $k$ people are in the array of people who will share a secret the probability that the people unknown to it will hear it.